# Amazon Selling Partner SP-API Inventory 403 error

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Anyone else have problems with the Amazon Selling Partner API endpoint "summaries" ?

I am trying to access the inventory summaries endpoint, from the US marketplace.
I am getting a 403 Forbidden response.
I have checked that the inventory endpoint access is allowed in Seller Central.
My code works for other endpoints, just this one is being rejected.

```
GET
https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/fba/inventory/v1/summaries?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER&granularityType=Marketplace&granularityId=ATVPDKIKX0DER
I set the header: Content-Type: application/json


Response:
statusCode: 403
content: {"errors": [ {
    "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
    "code": "Unauthorized", "details": "" } ]}
```

Comment: Did you find out what is causing the issue above? Facing the same issue with /fba/inventory/v1/summaries API on the SP-API Sandbox

Comment: Maybe your credentials is not allowed in US markets or your credentials is not allowed to access inventory.You may contact the selling partner api support for this

Comment: You can use your US credentials to access EU/AU/etc marketplace data.
If he is able to successfully make use of other SP-API endpoints, then he is just hitting the fba endpoint incorrectly.  These can be difficult to get working.
Whatever he does, do not bother contacting Amz SP-API support.  That is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

When you change permissions on Seller Central  you have to gen a  new Refresh Token.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by change permissions on Seller Central? Changing the "Roles" selected when your app was created?

Comment: Yes. Select additional roles, then gen a new token and use that.